# how to fix this nav?

Tags: css, navigation, css-transitions, navigationbar

anyone have any idea how to fix this navigation?

u can see the in first "item1" the in the "Menu1" the "Menu2" is work perfectly but on the 2nd 
item1 to the right one the "Menu2" is not work properly as it should be like the on the first menu.

how to fix this?

```
      #nav {
width: auto;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
left: 136px;
top: 45px;
  }
   #nav ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
  }
  #nav ul li {
float: left;
  }
  #nav ul li a {
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 30px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #0CF;
color: #FFF;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
transition: all 1s ease 0s;
border: thin solid #666;
    }
    #nav ul li a:hover {
background-color: #0C3;
     }
    #nav ul li ul {
height: 0px;
width: 102px;
z-index: 0;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
visibility: hidden;
top: 31px;
border-bottom-width: thin;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #666;
    }
    #nav ul li ul li {
/* [disabled]overflow: hidden; */
    }
    #nav ul li:hover ul {
height: 127px;
visibility: visible;
    }
    #nav ul li ul li a {
display: block;
color: #FFF;
position: relative;
bottom: auto;
background-color: #999;
border-top-width: thin;
border-right-width: thin;
border-bottom-width: thin;
border-left-width: thin;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
-moz-transition: all 1s;
-ms-transition: all 1s;
-o-transition: all 1s;
transition: all 1s;
border-top-color: #666;
border-bottom-color: #ccc;
border-right-color: #333;
border-left-color: #333;
    }
    #nav ul li ul li a:hover {
background-color: #666;
color: #0C3;
    }
    #nav ul li ul li ul {
position: absolute;
left: 102px;
top: 128px;
visibility: hidden;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
    }
    #nav ul li ul li:hover ul {
visibility: visible;
width: 102px;
    }
```

**html**

```
<nav id="nav">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
    <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li> 
         </ul>       
       </li> 
     </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li> 
      </ul>       
     </li> 
    </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: A jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: Could you please shorten the CSS to the relevant bits? The transitions and borders etc are a bit unrelated when it comes to a functionality standpoint

Comment: no i dont want i dont think so as like this.
But if u saw the problem please just fix it.

Comment: check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hsn0/u8z4r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/u8z4r/1/

The second child menu opens to the right of it's button on hover. You should begin using css classes to differentiate between elements. The second child dropdown menu I have the class `.left-menu` and moved the dropdown another 102px to the left.

```
<ul class="left-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li> 
</ul>
```

And:

```
#nav ul li ul li .left-menu {
    left: 204px;
}
```

Comment: thanx alot u raelly solve my problem. :) if i need more help will u do? how could i contact with u?

Comment: i have now add another 3rd menu and give that class to `3rd-menu` thats position i set to 408 why thats not working? :(

how do i fix like this problems? check your this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hsn0/u8z4r/2/

Comment: Hello Mr.beginner! The problem is that classes must begin with either an '_' or a letter, not a number. Try setting the class name to `.third-menu` and change your positioning like this: `left: 306px;`.

Comment: Oh thank you so much i like your teaching method :D. i wish i could like your post. I saw only 1 guy who help help me is only u . ;)